# Prove that $T $ is topologically transitive, and there exist two points $x,y$ with $O(x)≠O(y)$, then $X $ is infinite.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that $T $ is topologically transitive, and there exist two points $x,y$  with $O(x)≠O(y)$, then $X $ is infinite.

My attempt:

Suppose that T  is topologically transitive on $X$, then there exist $x,y \in X$  and $ϵ>0$, then set $U=B_ϵ(x)$  and $V=B_ϵ(y)$. Then, $T^n U∩V$  is nonempty. Two orbits $O(x)≠O(y)$, then they have different periodic points. How do I apply such things to prove that $X$  is infinite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $X$ is Hausdorff. Assume as well, for now, that $X$ is finite. Then $X$ is discrete, so each singleton $\{x\}$ is a neighborhood of the lone point $x \in X$ it contains. Given $x,y \in X$, there exist $n,m \in \mathbb N$ such that $f^n(x) = y$ and $f^m(y) = x$, so the forward orbits $O(x) = \{f^n(x) : n \in \mathbb N\}$ and $O(y)$ are the same set. So if there are two distinct orbits in $X$, by contraposition, the space $X$ cannot be finite.

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain more about the second sentence -  "then $X$ is a ...it contains"?

Comment: Sure ... in space satisfying the $T_1$ axiom (which is weaker than the Hausdorff axiom), every singleton $\{x\}$ is closed, so the complement $X \setminus \{x\}$ is open. If $X$ is finite, then any singleton can be realized as an intersection of finitely many of these open sets, so every singleton is open, and thus all unions of singletons (so, all subsets of $X$) are open; that's what it means to say a topological space is discrete.